# Want to replace Object tag in string by javascript

Tags: javascript, string, object

I want to replace object tag containing string in javascript with spaces.

```
var tmpSearchPhrase ='<object data="data:text/html;
base64,PHNjcmlkb21haW4pOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg=="></object>';
tmpSearchPhrase.replace(/<object .*>.*<\/object>/,"");
```

But it is not replacing object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't break the string and re-assign the return value of `replace` to `tmpSearchPhrase`

```
tmpSearchPhrase ='<object data="data:text/html;base64,PHNjcmlkb21haW4pOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg=="></object>';
tmpSearchPhrase = tmpSearchPhrase.replace(/<object .*>.*<\/object>/,"");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can't have a new line literal in a String, unless you escape it.

```
var tmpSearchPhrase ='<object data="data:text/html;
base64,PHNjcmlkb21haW4pOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg=="></object>';
// SyntaxError: Unexpected token ILLEGAL

var tmpSearchPhrase ='<object data="data:text/html;\
base64,PHNjcmlkb21haW4pOzwvc2NyaXB0Pg=="></object>';
// fine

tmpSearchPhrase.replace(/<object .*>.*<\/object>/,"");  // ""
```

You may also be forgetting to assign the result of `replace` to a variable.